# How to show a grid in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm trying to display a simple grid in Vaadin and am having trouble getting it to show up on the web page. All I get is a blank page with no errors. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
package com.example.testyui;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("testyui")
public class TestyUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = TestyUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

Grid grid = new Grid("Data Grid");

layout.addComponent(grid);
grid.setSizeFull();
layout.setExpandRatio(grid, 1);

grid.addColumn("firstName");
grid.addColumn("lastName");
grid.addColumn("salary");

grid.addColumn("address.streetAddress");
grid.addColumn("address.city");
grid.addColumn("address.country");

grid.setColumnOrder("firstName", "lastName", "salary",
        "address.streetAddress", "address.city", "address.country");

grid.isImmediate();
grid.isEditorActive();
grid.setEditorEnabled(true);

grid.addRow("Gene", "Hampton", "123", "TacoRoad", "Fiesta", "USA");
grid.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing setContent

```
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.setSizeFull(); // Use entire window
setContent(layout );   // Attach to the UI
```

Check

https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-architecture.html

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much! I added this line:  this.setContent(layout); and the table displayed properly.